# Error while using itemize in parbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am using itemize in `\parbox` and getting following error message

```
 \documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.95\textwidth} 
  \parbox[t][1.4cm][t]{\linewidth}{ \newline\begin{itemize}\item line1.\item  line2.\item line3.\end{itemize} } 
 \end{minipage}
 \end{document} 



! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 ...ne1.\item line2.\item line3.\end{itemize} }
```

How can i avoid such warning/error?

Answer (score 3):

Suppress the `\newline` just before `\begin{itemize}`.

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.95\textwidth} 
  \parbox[t][1.4cm][t]{\linewidth}{\begin{itemize}\item line1.\item  line2.\item line3.\end{itemize} } 
 \end{minipage}
 \end{document}
```

If you *really* need the `\newline` there, place something before it (a `\mbox{}`, for example):

```
 \documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.95\textwidth} 
  \parbox[t][1.4cm][t]{\linewidth}{\mbox{}\newline\begin{itemize}\item line1.\item  line2.\item line3.\end{itemize} } 
 \end{minipage}
 \end{document}
```

I am not sure why are you using the `\parbox` inside the `minipage` or why did you introduce the `\newline` there.

Comment: But i need to add one newline also.

Comment: @manish please see my updated answer.